# Problem loading an encrypted external hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, encryption

I have an encrypted Seagate drive. After plugging it in it does not automount so I tried using `sudo fdisk -l` and this is what I got as output.

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 81.7 MiB, 85692416 bytes, 167368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2785c02a

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 625141759 625139712 298.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2a471c67
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 3907029166 3907027119  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
\
```

Looking at the size of the displayed drives the next command was `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and the output I received was:

```
mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sbd1 does not exist.
```

What do I do now?

Comment: What was used to encrypt it?

Comment: I notice `Disklabel type: dos` and `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`. Was this disk last connected to a Windows system? Windows tends to leave disks connected to in it a Windows-specific state that Linux can't handle.

Comment: Yes it was Last connected to a windows laptop. SO what can I do now.?